# How to connect mapstatetoprops and mapdispathctoprops in React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

While running the below code I'm getting the error.

`TypeError: _this.props.signInUser is not a function`

Code:

```
import {signInUser} from '../actions/authAction'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 auth: state.auth,
 errors: state.errors
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
 hideModal: modelType => dispatch(hideModal())
});

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps,
 null,
 {signInUser}
 )(LoginModal);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the parameters correctly to `connect` function. The fourth param to connect is `options` which takes the following values within object

```
{
  context?: Object,
  pure?: boolean,
  areStatesEqual?: Function,
  areOwnPropsEqual?: Function,
  areStatePropsEqual?: Function,
  areMergedPropsEqual?: Function,
  forwardRef?: boolean,
}
```

and `signInUser` is not one of them. I suppose you mean to pass it on to mapDisptachToProps

```
import {signInUser} from '../actions/authAction'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 auth: state.auth,
 errors: state.errors
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
 hideModal: modelType => dispatch(hideModal()),
 signInUser: (...args) => dispatch(signInUser(...args));
});

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps,
)(LoginModal);
```